# Multiple saved preferences in android

Tags: android

I am very new to java and android but doing my best to make an app, basicaly I want a page with 6 text boxes on it, and each allows the user to type a 3 digit unique value into each, check a confirm box and then a button to save, then when the user revisits this part of the app the data will still be there, I managed to get it working for 1 box but if i add another it just duplicated box 1s value, here is my code for the class

public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
CheckBox cb;
EditText et, et1;
Button b;
String test;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    loadPrefs();
    cb.setChecked(false);       

}

private void loadPrefs() {

    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean cbValue = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBOX", false);
    String name = sp.getString("NAME", "Kg");
    if(cbValue){
        cb.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        cb.setChecked(false);
    }
    et.setText(name + (" kg"));
    }




private void savePrefs(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putBoolean(key, value);
    edit.commit();
}

private void savePrefs(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putString(key, value);
    edit.commit();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    savePrefs("CHECKBOX", cb.isChecked());
    if (cb.isChecked())
        savePrefs("NAME", et.getText().toString());

    finish();
}
```

}

any help would be greatly appreciated as time is short :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

What you're not coding is saving the data.

```
 SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 boolean cbValue = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBOX", false);
```

What the second line does is says, is "CHECKBOX" a saved sharedpreference? No, it isn't. Okay let's get the default value of false then.

What you need to do is save it using this:

```
SharedPreferences.editor Editor = sp.edit();
Editor.putBoolean("CHECKBOX",true);
Editor.commit();
```

The first line defines the sharedpreference editor. The next line saves the boolean value true under the in effect filename (key) of CHECKBOX and then the commit line says, okay do the above and finalise it so that now whenever I call:

```
sp.getBoolean("CHECKBOX",false);
```

I will get true because I won't have to use the default value of false.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make this easy for you...

First, in your proferences xml, each text box and check box needs it's own key.

Secondly, to make it easy for you to read/understand you should assign a different name for the pref save method void savePrefs(String key, String value).

For example String: void savePrefsString(String key, String value)

For example boolean: void savePrefsBoolean(String key, boolean value)

Be sure each one is called appropriately (savePrefsBoolean for boolean and savePrefsString for edittext).

Then for each edit text you will want to retrieve the key from preferences for that edittext.

Example:

```
String name1 = sp.getString("NAME1", "Kg");
String name2 = sp.getString("NAME2", "Kg");
String name3 = sp.getString("NAME3", "Kg");
```

Then:

```
et1.setText(name1 + (" kg"));
et2.setText(name2 + (" kg"));
et3.setText(name1 + (" kg"));
```

Do the same for your checkboxes (they are actually true/false booleans).

Example:

```
boolean cb1 = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBOX1", false); //false is default value
boolean cb2 = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBOX1", false);
boolean cb3 = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBOX1", false);
```

Then to set value from prefs:

```
if(cb1){
        cb1.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        cb1.setChecked(false);
    }
```

and to save what the user has pressed:

```
savePrefsBoolean("CHECKBOX1", cb1.isChecked()); // get check value of checkbox 
savePrefsBoolean("CHECKBOX2", cb2.isChecked());
savePrefsBoolean("CHECKBOX3", cb3.isChecked());
```